# How to check if there are any free blocks in the middle of MyISAM datafile?

Tags: mysql, insert, myisam

I'm trying to verify that I need using `INSERT DELAYED` in MySQL. The docs state that:

> For MyISAM tables, if there are no free blocks in the middle of the
>   data file, concurrent SELECT and INSERT statements are supported.
>   Under these circumstances, you very seldom need to use INSERT DELAYED
>   with MyISAM.

I'm more or less sure that this is the case in my application, but I wonder if there's a way to check if there are free blocks in the middle of the data file?

I'm not sure if benchmarking would cut it, since it seems possible to choose queries for benchmarking in a way that wouldn't reflect all the cases.